# when and why would you prefer to define your own LinkedList class from scratch rather than useing java.util.LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

if java has provided the LinkedList class that would make your life a lot easier ... what would be a good reason for a developer not to use the provided LinkedLIst and build own LinkedList from scratch

Comment: Considering you hardly have a reason to use `java.util.LinkedList`... basically never.

Comment: Because otherwise you fail the class. Can't think of any other reason.

Comment: If you are asked to in the coding interview..

Comment: A developer may hope to improve [some of the properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist/322742#322742) of `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 1):

`LinkedList` implementation in Java is a Doubly-linked list. So it will take more memory space than Singly linked list. So, if your application is **too much memory critical** then you can think to implement a Singly linked list implementation. However, some operation in a Doubly-linked list is faster than a single linked list, you need to keep in mind the performance aspect also.